# Problem with beamerthemesplit package

Tags: beamer

Just turn from PowerPoint to Latex for slides:). A problem encountered:

Templates from beamerthemesplit can't be properly applied as the snapshot below. What may be the reason? BTW, are there any more templates to use?

Thanks and Best Regards.

[image]

---

UPDATE:

Here is the .tex document.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}

\title{\LaTeX presentations with Beamer}
\author{******}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titilepage}
\end{document}
```

My working environment is:

pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.10-2.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) & kpathsea version 5.0.0

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please provide a MWE that demonstrates the problem- it'll help folks who might be able to solve the problem :)

Comment: @cmhughes Thanks for the advice. Update my post:)

Comment: Use it as follows and let us know if things work as expected: `\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{split}
\title{\LaTeX presentations with Beamer}
\author{******}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}`

Comment: @percusse An error is issued saying: File `split.sty' not found. Anything help?

Comment: `split` is a built-in theme of beamer. So if beamer is installed correctly it should not have any problems finding it. This is probably an installation issue. I guess you are using `PDFLaTeX` anyway so it's not a wrong compiler problem.

Comment: @percusse Thanks, I get it. I remove and re-install `latex-beam`, the problem is still there. Is there a possibility the problem related to other latex package?

Comment: @diabonas: OK. I'll delete my comments shortly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two points about your [minimal  working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that):

- You use `\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}` to load the theme. However, it's better to use the correct [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) command `\usetheme{split}` to do that instead (although the former should work in principle).
- The [`beamer` manual (section 15.7)](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsection.15.7) says about the `split` theme:

  > Earlier versions of `beamer` included some further themes. These themes are still available for compatibility, though they are now implemented differently (they also mainly install appropriate color, font, inner, and outer
  >   themes). However, they may or may not honor color themes and they will not be supported in the future. The
  >   following list shows which of the new themes should be used instead of the old themes.
  >
  > [...]
  >
  > `split`       Try `Malmoe` instead.

So you should try something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Malmoe}
\title{\LaTeX{} presentations with Beamer}
\author{******}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```